# How to have display feed switch automatically between one screen active at a time in a Monitor / TV set-up?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

I have a monitor and a TV plugged into my PCs graphics card. The monitor is using a DP Cable the TV an HDMI. I'd like to have one screen active at a time. I want to have my desktop streamed to my monitor by default when I work for example, and when I turn on my TV to game, for my monitor to automatically turn off / sleep and the feed to switch to the TV, and when I turn off the TV for the feed to go back to the monitor.
The next best thing I've found is Win + P and the "Second monitor only" setting, but I want my monitor to turn back on once the TV is off, and for it to happen automatically. A software solution would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use software like `DisplayFusion` or `MultiMonitorTool` to automatically transition between your monitor and TV. You can use these tools to construct profiles or scripts that switch the display feed based on triggers or events. You can also manually change the stream in Windows display settings by pressing Win + P, however, automation based on TV on/off events requires third-party software or scripts.

Comment: Could you tell me a way to do it in either program? Tried looking for it, and messing around with both the programs on my own but couldn't get it to work.